# Firebase, query specific keys from a large set of data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much for your time.

Let us say, there is a large set of articles under `Articles` node.

```
"Articles" : {
"article1Key" : {
  "articleAuthor" : "Author",
  "articleFavByNo" : 21,
  "articleKey" : "Key",
  "articleName" : "Name",
  "articlePostedOn" : "21/07/11",
  "articleTopic" : "Topic"
},
"article2Key" : {
  "articleAuthor" : "Author",
  "articleFavByNo" : 21,
  "articleKey" : "Key",
  "articleName" : "Name",
  "articlePostedOn" : "21/07/11",
  "articleTopic" : "Topic"
},
...
"article10Key" : {
  "articleAuthor" : "Author",
  "articleFavByNo" : 21,
  "articleKey" : "Key",
  "articleName" : "Name",
  "articlePostedOn" : "21/07/11",
  "articleTopic" : "Topic"
}
```

The articles are posted by some authors. Registered user can browse through the articles, and like them. The liked `articles keys` are stored in `Users` profile under `favArticles` node. Since, the article contains huge amount of data under it, only the `key` and `name` of the article is stored under `User` profile.

```
"Users" : {
"ZtlIQ2d1qJT1XpmHuGxwFSwaiEy2" : {
  "emailId" : "vs@gmail.com",
  "favArticles" : {
    "article1Key" : {
      "name" : "article1"
    },
    "article7Key" : {
      "name" : "article7"
    },
    "article4Key" : {
      "name" : "article4"
    }
  },
  "firstName" : "Vimala",
  "image" : "default",
  "lastName" : "Sridhar"
}
}
```

Let us say that the user has liked some 50 articles out of 1000. Now if I want to display the User favorite articles in a RecyclerView, how should I write my query to pick the specific articles from the article list?

Comment: My plan is to put the `favArticles key` in a arrayList. For each key in the arrayList attach a valueEvenListener and get the DataSnapShot of the article and display. I don't know whether this is the right way to achieve my goal. Also, this way, I cannot use RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already keep a list of the favorites for each user, you'd just:

1. load that list of favorites
2. iterate over it
3. load the references article for each

If you're worried about the performance of this loop-and-load: Firebase loads all the articles in step 3 over the same connection, so the requests are pipelined. For reasonable numbers of articles, this is actually quite fast. See my answer here for more details: [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)